# php header function not redirecting as needed

Tags: php, redirect

This is a simple question which makes it painfully obvious that I need to take a php class...

I have as the first part of a an if / else statement that reads:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()){
//echo "user is signed in<P>";
header("Location: user-homepage.php");
```

so if the user is logged in and clicks a link that directs to /register.php, they should instead be redirected to the user-homepage.php.

What happens is they are directed instead directed to /register.php/user-homepage.php

My code is adding /user-homepage.php to the address instead of replacing /register.php with /user-homepage.php

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an absolute path rather than a relative one:

```
header("Location: /user-homepage.php");
```

Comment: This is what I did in Wordpess and it fixed the issue. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
header("Location: http://your_domain.com/user-homepage.php");
```

The [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) says to use Absolute URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You have used a relative file path.  Try adding a forward slash to make it relative to the domain root.

```
header("Location: /user-homepage.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

As given in section 14.30 of [RFC 2616, "HTTP 1.1"](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), use an absolute URL in the `Location` header.